# Can a planetary system orbit two black holes instead of one sun?

Tags: black-holes, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, solar-system, three-body-problem

A comic book depicts an exoplanetary system in another galaxy that orbits two black holes instead of a sun. Or it was a life-bearing exoplanet that was in proximity of two black holes as if they were moons to it, but which provided energy to that planet's inhabitants. Can such a formation exist in real space and exhibit this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

A planet could orbit within the habitable zone of two stars, but it is hard to imagine life existing on a planet orbiting one black hole, let alone two. Black holes could funnel CMB photons into a narrow beam just on the edge of their shadow, and blue-shift them into visible light, but to receive enough light to make the planet habitable, the planet would have to be orbiting ridiculously close, so close in fact that the black hole would have to be spinning at less than a hundred millionth of a percent less than the speed of light to keep the planet from falling in. I assume that in this comic book world, the planet would be roughly the same distance from both black holes, and it is impossible for a large amount of light to arrive at a planet thusly positioned.

The space around this system would have to be completely without debris as well, because if any fell in, it would send out a burst of radiation that would kill anything living nearby. So, no. I do not see any way that a system like this would ever be possible.

Comment: *The black hole would have to be spinning at less than a hundred millionth of a percent less than the speed of light to keep the planet from falling in.* How did you obtain this number?

Comment: This answer is me echoing something my physics teacher told me when I asked him a similar question about a planet orbiting a black hole like in the movie Interstellar. He showed me the math behind frame dragging but I can't for the life of me remember what exact distance I would have to plug into the relativity calculator.

Comment: The black hole in Interstellar called Gargantua is orbited by a planet that experiences extreme time dilation because of its proximity to the black hole. Is this not an example of a planetary system that orbits a black hole? Is there no real-life counterpart to Gargantua?

Comment: There technically is, but the planet could not orbit two black holes at the same time like in the Kepler 47 system.

Comment: *Like planets orbit two suns in Kepler 47

Comment: If it's at least technically possible for planets to orbit one black hole at least, would that black hole be hot enough to nurture life on that planet?

Comment: Yes, it would. If Miller's planet from Intersteller were not so covered in tsunamis, they could have colonized it! If your planet were orbiting just one black hole, I suppose you could pop another one into the general vicinity to get something close to that comic book world.